# how to print intermediate result in function composition

Tags: haskell

(The full code is at the end of the question.)

I am trying to print the intermediate result of  `showRow`  without `beside`

With this code loaded first into ghci:

```
-- Tic-tac-toe example from chapter 11 of Programming in Haskell,
-- Graham Hutton, Cambridge University Press, 2016.

-- Basic declarations

import Data.Char
import Data.List
import System.IO

size :: Int
size = 3

type Grid = [[Player]]

data Player = O | B | X
              deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

grid :: Grid
grid = [[B,O,O],[O,X,O],[X,X,X]]

next :: Player -> Player
next O = X
next B = B
next X = O

-- Grid utilities

empty :: Grid 
empty = replicate size (replicate size B)

full :: Grid -> Bool
full = all (/= B) . concat

turn :: Grid -> Player
turn g = if os <= xs then O else X
         where
            os = length (filter (== O) ps)
            xs = length (filter (== X) ps)
            ps = concat g

wins :: Player -> Grid -> Bool
wins p g = any line (rows ++ cols ++ dias)
           where
              line = all (== p)
              rows = g
              cols = transpose g
              dias = [diag g, diag (map reverse g)]

diag :: Grid -> [Player]
diag g = [g !! n !! n | n <- [0..size-1]]

won :: Grid -> Bool
won g = wins O g || wins X g

-- Displaying a grid

putGrid :: Grid -> IO ()
putGrid =
   putStrLn . unlines . concat . interleave bar . map showRow
   where bar = [replicate ((size*4)-1) '-']

showRow :: [Player] -> [String]
showRow = beside . interleave bar . map showPlayer
          where
             beside = foldr1 (zipWith (++))
             bar    = replicate 3 "|"

showPlayer :: Player -> [String]
showPlayer O = ["   ", " O ", "   "]
showPlayer B = ["   ", "   ", "   "]
showPlayer X = ["   ", " X ", "   "]

interleave :: a -> [a] -> [a]
interleave x []     = []
interleave x [y]    = [y]
interleave x (y:ys) = y : x : interleave x ys
```

`showRow row` is working:

```
*Main> row = grid !! 0
*Main> showRow row
["   |   |   ","   | O | O ","   |   |   "]
```

But not the following:

```
*Main> row = grid !! 0
*Main> (interleave replicate 3 "|") . (map showPlayer row)

<interactive>:9:2: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char] -> b0 -> c’
                  with actual type ‘[Int -> a0 -> [a0]]’
    • The function ‘interleave’ is applied to three arguments,
      but its type ‘(Int -> a0 -> [a0])
                    -> [Int -> a0 -> [a0]] -> [Int -> a0 -> [a0]]’
      has only two
      In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely
        ‘(interleave replicate 3 "|")’
      In the expression:
        (interleave replicate 3 "|") . (map showPlayer row)
    • Relevant bindings include
        it :: a -> c (bound at <interactive>:9:1)

<interactive>:9:33: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘a -> b0’
                  with actual type ‘[[String]]’
    • Possible cause: ‘map’ is applied to too many arguments
      In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘(map showPlayer row)’
      In the expression:
        (interleave replicate 3 "|") . (map showPlayer row)
      In an equation for ‘it’:
          it = (interleave replicate 3 "|") . (map showPlayer row)
    • Relevant bindings include
        it :: a -> c (bound at <interactive>:9:1)
```

The code you need to load into ghci is also in the following, chapter 11

https://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/pih.html

Comment: You likely should use `interleave (replicate 3 "|") (map showPlayer row)`, instead of `(interleave replicate 3 "|") . (map showPlayer row)`.

Comment: Tried, not working

Comment: ah, sorry I mean `interleave "|" (map showPlayer row)`

Comment: The point here is to explore why the function `showRow` cannot work partially without `beside`

Comment: FYI, `interleave` is `Data.List.intersperse`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to print the intermediate result of showRow without beside

Mind the dollars and parenthesis:

```
 λ> 
 λ> (interleave $ replicate 3 "|") $ (map showPlayer row)
 [["   ","   ","   "],["|","|","|"],["   "," O ","   "],["|","|","|"],["   "," O ","   "]]
 λ> 
 λ> interleave  (replicate 3 "|")  (map showPlayer row)
 [["   ","   ","   "],["|","|","|"],["   "," O ","   "],["|","|","|"],["   "," O ","   "]]
 λ>
```

**Really long explanation:** your initial expression `(interleave replicate 3 "|") . (map showPlayer row)` used the *dot/period function composition operator*, that is '.' in Haskell source code, '·' or '∘' in mathematical texts. This could only work if `(map showPlayer row)` were composable, that is, were a *function* of some sort. But that expression is a value expression of type `[[String]]`. Hence it is not a function, and thus cannot be composed. This is what the long and unwieldly compiler error message wants to tell you.

More generally, perhaps you could use the Haskell thing for what is known as “*à la printf() debugging style*” in imperative programming circles.

You would need:

```
import Debug.Trace
```

By some special privilege, function `trace` has the capability of printing stuff on stderr while remaining outside the IO monad. The expression `trace debugMsg xyz` evaluates to just xyz.

You could rewrite your `showRow` function like this:

```
showRow1 :: [Player] -> [String]
showRow1 players = let  beside = foldr1 (zipWith (++))
                        bar    = replicate 3 "|"
                        res1   = map showPlayer players
                        res2nd = interleave bar res1  -- no debug
                        msg    = "Trace:  res2 = " ++ show res2nd
                        res2   = trace msg res2nd
                   in  beside res2
```

Test under ghci:

```
 λ> 
 λ> showRow $ [O,B,X]
 ["   |   |   "," O |   | X ","   |   |   "]
 λ> 
 λ> showRow1 $ [O,B,X]
 Trace:  res2 = [["   "," O ","   "],["|","|","|"],["   ","   ","   "],["|","|","|"],["   "," X ","   "]]
 ["   |   |   "," O |   | X ","   |   |   "]
 λ>
```